# [Jenkins]Build c++ solution file using devenv.com

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-studio-2008, jenkins, batch-processing

I have a VS2008 solution file named MySolution.sln containing three projects ProjectName1, ProjectName2, ProjectName3 and ProjectName4. I am using jenkins to build the solution(to built only ProjectName1/2/3 and not ProjectName4). Below is the batch which has been provided to jenkins.

The issue is whenever lets say, the statement "%VSDIR%\devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /Build "Release|x64" /Project ProjectName1 failed to build the particular project my %errorlevel% is not updated to non negative integer (>0). Irrespective of pass/fail the %errorlevel% is always "0"

The way jenkins calls this is

```
cmd /c call C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson343434346343.bat
```

Any ideas on this?

Batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
set VSDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE

"%VSDIR%\devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /Clean "Release|x64"

"%VSDIR%\devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /Build "Release|x64" /Project ProjectName1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  "%VSDIR%\devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /Build "Release|x64" /Project ProjectName2
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    "%VSDIR%\devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /Build "Release|x64" /Project ProjectName3
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    ) ELSE (
        echo "Failed to build ProjectName3"
    )
  ) ELSE (
      echo "Failed to build ProjectName2"
  )
) ELSE (
    echo "Failed to build ProjectName1"
)
unset VSDIR
```

Answer (score 0):

just use MSBuild plug-in. You are all set.

Answer (score 0):

I have several suggestions to make this simpler and more reliable.

You do not need to do a separate call to **devenv.com** in order to do a **/Clean**.  Simply replace the **/Build** command in subsequent **devenv.com** calls with **/Rebuild**, which will clean before building from scratch.

After each call to **devenv.com** immediately do:

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error building Solution X & goto some-label
```

This will detect any ERRORLEVEL of 1 *or higher*.  This approach will not require any parentheses or ELSE clauses, and avoid the need to nest the subsequent IF statements.

You can also build the 3 (out of 4) projects with a single **devenv.com** call.  This would require you to specify a *solution build configuration* that excludes (skips) the fourth project.  For example:

```
"%VSDIR%\devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /Rebuild "Release-Jenkins|x64"
```

The above approach requires first loading the solution in the Visual Studio IDE, going into the Configuration Manager, and creating a new solution build configuration (based on a copy of the existing **Release** build configuration).  Name the new solution build configuration **Release-Jenkins** (or whatever), then make sure the project you wish to exclude is unchecked for each of the variations of **Win32/x64/AnyCPU**.  Also, be sure to UNCHECK the checkbox to **Create new project configurations**, as you do not require any new project configurations.  Also create a corresponding solution build configuration for **Debug** builds, i.e. **Debug-Jenkins**.

The **unset** command works in bash, but not for **cmd.exe** shells.  To undefine the variable, do:

```
set VSDIR=
```

with nothing following the = sign.  Or even better, add the command **SETLOCAL** on its own line immediately after **@ECHO OFF**.  The **SETLOCAL** statement will ensure any environment variable changes are discarded when the batch file exits.